# MegaMenu structure in sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to move a megamenu into the database and was wondering what the best structure for this would be. Is this structure suitable or is there a better way?

Most of my searches come up with using a self referencing table.

The menu consists of the main headers.
Each menu under it will have many sub headers and then links under it.
Some menus and links can be restricted by security roles.
Some will need additional classes and or using data elements bound to jquery events.

Here is what I was thinking:

dbo.MainMenu Table

```
ID int not null primary key identity(1,1)
ParentID int null foreign key references MainMenu(ID)
Title varchar(6) not null
Path varchar(255) null --url
Target varchar(10) null --ex: _blank
Class varchar(30) null --classes for styling or jquery bound
```

Security.MainMenu table

```
ID int not null primary key references MainMenu(ID)
SecurityRoleID int not null foreign key references Security.Role
```

The security table will allow me to add multiple security roles per item if restricted access is required so it's not shown to the user. The back end wont allow access anyways but I don't want it presented.

This will be running on SQL server 2016.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: Your Security.MainMenu should have a composite key of ID and SecurityRoleID instead of single primary key. Otherwise, each menu item would only support a single SecurityRoleID to be linked.

Comment: @JasonW Thanks that slipped my mind.

Comment: What you have defined here is known as an adjacency list. They are very common for this type of thing. However, the nested sets model is much more efficient because you can often avoid using recursion. And moving elements in a nested set model is super simple. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model